# How to restrict Firebase API keys in the Google Cloud console

Tags: android, firebase, security, mobile, google-api

I have a question about the interplay of the Google Cloud API keys and the keys, that are used by Firebase:

I want to add **Google API key restrictions** for two apps (Android & iOS). So I created two new keys (Android + iOS) in the *Google Cloud Console*, that should replace the old overpowered and unrestricted prod key, which was used for both platforms. I was able to add the desired restrictions for both new keys, but how can I change the keys in *Firebase console* (= in the google-services.json file for Android)? When I try to download the google-services.json file, the key is still the old one. And I don't see any option to update this key in the Firebase Console. Firebase is also still using the old key when I add a new app with package-name and fingerprint to the Firebase project.

See the docs: https://cloud.google.com/api-keys/docs/add-restrictions-api-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how Firebase updates its keys:

> When you first obtain your app's Firebase config file/object, Firebase
> checks if there are any existing API keys in your project that have
> "Application Restrictions" that match the app (for example, a matching
> bundle ID for the Apple app).
>
> If Firebase doesn't find any restricted keys that match, then it will
> list in the config file/object the iOS key for Apple apps, the Android
> key for Android apps, and the Browser key for web apps (assuming that
> these keys exist and have no "Application Restrictions" that keep them
> from matching to that app).

So I had to configure the Android package-id and the fingerprint of the App in the Google Console right, so it gets synchronized when I create a new Firebase project.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#faq-auto-matching-app-to-key

Comment: "it gets synchronized when I create a new Firebase project."  does this mean it is not possible to restrict api key access for an existing project?